# class of variable is list in data.table

Tags: r, list, data.table, extract

Suppose I have the following data:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
Data <- 
  data.table(A = c("foo 32.3 56.2421 4.5 3.66", 
                 "365.11 9812.3 foooo 5.66 8.31",
                 ""))
```

In some rows there are four numbers, in some there aren't.
I want to have two new columns with these numbers. This is my code for that:

```
Data[, str_c("Number", 1:4) := str_extract_all(A, "\\d+\\.\\d") %>% transpose]
```

It works quite fine but in the third line I get `NULL` in the variables `Number1` to `Number2` (I want `NA`).

The real problem is that the class of `Number1` to `Number4` are `list` but I want `character` (or even better `numeric` in the next step).

How can I achieve this? I want to use a code with an extraction and with `data.table`.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the values to numeric with `lapply`, if the values are absent return `NA` and then transpose the result to create two new columns.

```
library(data.table)

Data[, c("Number1", "Number2") := lapply(stringr::str_extract_all(A, "\\d+"), 
       function(x) if(length(x)) as.numeric(x) else NA) %>% transpose()]

Data

#                A Number1 Number2
#1:      foo 32 56      32      56
#2: 365 9812 foooo     365    9812
#3:                     NA      NA
```

---

Using `tidyr`'s `extract` you can do :

```
tidyr::extract(Data, A, c("Number1", "Number2"), 
              '(\\d+).*(\\d+)', remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE)

#                A Number1 Number2
#1:      foo 32 56      32       6
#2: 365 9812 foooo     365       2
#3:                     NA      NA
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I'm searching for an easy solution that my customers will easily understand.

Comment: @TobiSonne What do you mean?

Comment: I think the part `function(x) if(length(x)) as.numeric(x) else NA)` is quite complicated (not for ME, but to explain). And I especially don't want to explain why there are `NULL` values. I'm seaching for something like in `tidyr`'s `separate` where missing values are filled with `NA` automatically (but I don't want to use separate here because of the structure of my real data).

Comment: You can use `tidyr`'s `extract` function then.

Comment: Thank you! Did not know that function. Unfortunately for my real case this does not work, too. I have four numbers and they are with decimals and I don't want to use the regex `"(\\d+\\.\\d+).*(\\d+\\.\\d+).*(\\d+\\.\\d+).*(\\d+\\.\\d+)`

Comment: You seem to keep on adding constraints after every update. You should post all these constraints when positing your original question and not after the answer is posted. Reading your question nobody can guess about all of your constraints unless you explicitly tell us. We can only answer based on the data and information you provide.

Comment: Yes, thought about that myself, sorry!